# AWS Static IP to Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, amazon-elb

Is it possible to assign a static IP to an AWS load balancer without the need to move your NS records to Route 53?

I basically just want to create an A record from my domain to point to the ELB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Elastic Load Balancer is a distributed system. It does not have a single public IP address. Instead, when you create an ELB, you are given a DNS name such as ExampleDomainELB-67854125.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 
Amazon gives a facility to set up a DNS CNAME entry pointing for e.g. www.exampledomain.com to the ELB-supplied DNS name.

Also, ELB is directing to one of your instances. Hence, creating a static IP address for ELB will not be feasible.

So as a solution if you need to set your 'A' record from your domain pointing to your ELB in Route53 :

1. Select 'Yes' for Alias.
2. Set Alias target as your Load Balancer DNS.

Second way is similar by selecting the CNAME in Route53 and pointing the Alias Target to your ELB.

This should help.

Answer (score 5):

AWS Load Balancer is a very generic term.

You currently have three options for load balancing in AWS:

- Application Load Balancers (ALB)
- Network Load Balancers (NLB)
- Classic/Elastic Load Balancers (ELB)

Of those three only one, the Network Load Balancer can have a static IP address.  It's listed in the reference below.

> Support for static IP addresses for the load balancer. You can also assign one Elastic IP address per subnet enabled for the load balancer.

It is also possible to "glue" an NLB and ALB together to provide a static IP address and application load balancer functionality.  In general you allow a lambda to populate an NLB Target group with your ALB info.  It's outside the scope of this answer but the link is below.

If you're using Route53 you can create an A record Alias for your Load Balancer.
If you're not, you can use a CNAME.

**References**

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/introduction.html
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-static-ip-addresses-for-application-load-balancers/

Answer (score 1):

ELB manage the IP for you, it just gives you the DNS name. So you can't control the IP behind it.

If you need an A record than you need to use A record alias from Route53.
Without using Route 53, you can use CNAME instead of A record.